Stop running application on update with MSI Installer
I have an application that is installed with MSI installer that I build using Microsoft Setup Project.
The application is installed correctly, but when I build new MSI installer with higher version, I also update the PackageCode and ProductCode (not the UpgradeCode), when I run this new MSI file, I get the FileInUse pop-up but there is no option to close the running application, only Retry, Continue and Exit Installations.
If I click continue then I get the error: Access denied to 'path of the running application exe'
I tried to add CustomActions on Install, that should stop the running application, but the custom actions are not executed on time (I can't change the schedule inside the table, that will not work for the way how we distribute the MSI file to the clients)
Is there any better solution on how to stop the running application while updating?
Note When I uninstall the application, then the RestartManager can detect the running application WPF desktop app, and successfully shut-down the app. (There is a bit different FileInUse dialog, that has option to close the running files/applications )
